# How do I get archive to work in Mail.app in Lion?

Tags: macos, mail.app, gmail, imap, archive

I can't get archive to work on Lion. When I choose archive in Mail.app it creates a folder called Archived. That's not what I want. When I choose delete it doesn't remove the message from my inbox. It is just greyed out. Right now I leave the messages in the inbox and archive them from my iPhone, which works great. Please help me get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're okay using Mail's delete function as archive, then simply go into Mail > Preferences > Accounts > Gmail > Mailbox Behaviors and *deselect* both of these options:

[ ] Move deleted messages to the Trash mailbox

[ ] Store deleted messages on the server

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of settings]

Then when you delete a message in Mail, you'll be archiving it.

Reference here:

https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78892

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it turned out that I had to enable Auto-expunge in gmail settings; otherwise actions performed in Mail don't sync up to the gmail server in a timely fashion. Just enable auto-expunge.